# R XML package not getting all of the information on the page

Tags: xml, r, parsing

I'm having an issue with importing the html of a site that includes a table that is filled using (what I suspect) javascript. If I save the website as source code on my HD I can easily do what I want using the XML package in R; if I try and read the site directly using

```
doc <- htmlTreeParse(url)
```

the data from the table is missing. I suspect this is because htmlTreeParse does not handle concurrent requests. Is there a way to make the xml package request the "full" website?

I've been able to get the full html with Python and the urllib2 library using

```
req = urllib2.Request('http://www.theURL.com')
response = urllib2.urlopen(req)
the_page = response.read()
```

but I would prefer to stick with R.

The site I've been messing around with is http://bigcharts.marketwatch.com/reports/bigmovers.asp?date=20130104&data=1&start=1&report=1&report_country_code=US

Thank you.

Comment: How 'bout `readHTMLTable(url, stringsAsFactors=FALSE)[[1]]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using Gsee comment I get this ,

```
url.xml <- 'http://bigcharts.marketwatch.com/reports/bigmovers.asp?date=20130104&data=1&start=1&report=1&report_country_code=US'
dat <- readHTMLTable(url.xml)
  dat[[1]]
   Rank                      Company Name Symbol Go to: % Increase in Price     Volume Closing Price Price Change P/E Ratio
1     1             US Airways Group Inc.    LCC                      7.83% 12,049,183         14.73        +1.07       N/A
2     2                         Yelp Inc.   YELP                      6.80%  1,966,749         21.52        +1.37       N/A
3     3  Arcos Dorados Holdings Inc. Cl A   ARCO                      6.69%  2,613,174         13.72        +0.86       N/A
4     4 Thompson Creek Metals Co. Inc. Un  TC.PT                      6.21%     30,188         22.05        +1.29       N/A
5     5 Nationstar Mortgage Holdings Inc.    NSM                      6.13%  3,054,272         33.23        +1.92       N/A
6     6        Consolidated Graphics Inc.    CGX                      6.05%     60,052         36.31        +2.07       N/A
7     7         Bonanza Creek Energy Inc.   BCEI                      5.95%  1,268,468         30.10        +1.69       N/A
8     8                    Huntsman Corp.    HUN                      5.72%  9,176,196         17.74        +0.96       N/A
9     9             Assured Guaranty Ltd.    AGO                      5.54%  1,853,300         15.62        +0.82       N/A
10   10              Dollar General Corp.     DG                      5.36%  8,772,419         44.60        +2.27       N/A
```

Maybe you need to coerce `Volume` to numeric.

```
as.numeric(gsub("[^0-9.-]+","",dat[[1]]$Volume))
 [1] 12049183  1966749  2613174    30188  3054272    60052  1268468  9176196  1853300  8772419
```

Comment: I hope I didn't accidentally downvote the answer because I certainly didn't mean to. Works as it should perfect.

Comment: @JørgenKippers I don't think you have enough score to dwonvote! But you can accept the answer using the check box at the left..Of course if this answers your needs.